# How can I measure code coverage in a WCF app

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, code-coverage

I have a WCF App and an adiccional functionals test project into the same solution.

example. the WCF Project with exposes a Method1

and my functionals test project invoke a wcfClient.Method1 to test the results

when I run the code coverage the results are about the functionals test project not over the wcf project.

How can measure the coverage on the WCF project?

Regards,

Comment: What are you using to get your coverage data, there are many options out there? How are you executing your tests?

Answer (score 0):

If WCF is self hosted you would need to run its exe using NCover (or your coverage tool of choice). The results file will be separate from your client side resutls since this is a different process.